# Skip outter loop if meet condition

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Hello I have 3 loop as follow:

```
for i1 in loop1:
    for i2 in loop2:
        for i3 in loop3:
            do sth here
```

now I have a condition for `loop1` that if the condition is met then execute `loop1` if not we run `loop2` and `loop3` only.

I know that in standard way it is:

```
if condition==True:
    for i1 in loop1:
        for i2 in loop2:
            for i3 in loop3:
                do sth
else:
    for i2 in loop2:
        for i3 in loop3:
            do sth
```

However, I am looking for some way that is compact like:

```
for i1 in loop1 if condition==True then do otherwise skip go to next inner loop
    for i2 in loop2:
        for i3 in loop3:
            do sth
```

Comment: Maybe try to put the two inner loops to separate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way I approach this is:

```
for i1 in loop1 if Condition else [0]:
    for i2 in loop2:
        for i3 in loop3:
            do sth
```

Of course, this assumes i1 is never read in either case. [Edit, made it more compact]

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can you help me elaborate on the code a little bit more? I still don't get it

Comment: Sorry, I hit the wrong key and put up a partial answer. Now it ought to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension if you are dealing with lists. Example: `newlist = [x if 5 > 3 else 0 for x in range(3)]`